# How to paginate comments for detail_view?

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a simple blog and I need paginate comments for each posts but I don't know how to do it.
Thanks for help!
There is my models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=230, default='Post')
    text = models.TextField()
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

There is my views:

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'user/post.html'
    model = Post

def comment_view(request, pk):
    form = CommentCreateForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.user
            comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            Comment.objects.create(username=username, comment=comment, post_id=pk)
            return redirect('PostDetail', pk)
    return render(request, 'user/comment_view.html', {'form': form})
```

And there is my template:

```
{ object.title }}
    {% if object.author.id  %}
    <a href="{% url 'public_profile' object.author.id %}">{{ object.author }}</a>
    {% endif %}
<p>{{ object.text }}</p>
    <h4>Comments</h4>
{% for comment in object.comment_set.all %}
    {{ comment.username }}
    <p>{{ comment }}</p>
{% endfor %}
<p><a href="{% url 'comment_view' object.id %}">Leave comment</a></p>
```

Is it real to paginate comments?

How I should paginate comments in detail_view?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is like slicing the data. So what you can do is just filter all the data then slice it.

```
    products= Products.obejcts.all()
    page_no=1 #take it from frontend
    page_size = 10 #add how much data you want to show in one page.
    offset = (page_no - 1) * page_size
    products = products[offset:offset + page_size] #slicing of data-> [10:10+10] so it give 10 data list for page_no =1 
    base_url = request.build_absolute_uri()
    next_, prev_ = get_next_prev_url(
        base_url,
        page_no,
        page_size
    )
```

Function to get_next_preve_url

```
   from urllib import parse as url_parse
   def replace_query_param(url, key, val):
    """
    Given a URL and a key/val pair, set or replace an item in the query
    parameters of the URL, and return the new URL.
    """
    result = url_parse.urlparse(url)
    query_dict = url_parse.parse_qs(result.query, keep_blank_values=True)
    query_dict[key] = [val]
    query = url_parse.urlencode(sorted(list(query_dict.items())), doseq=True)
    return url_parse.urlunsplit((result.scheme, result.netloc, result.path, query, result.fragment))

  



     def get_next_prev_url(url, page_no, result_count, page_len):
            page_param = 'page_no'
            max_page_no = int(result_count / page_len) + int(result_count % page_len != 0)
            next_link = prev_link = None
            if max_page_no > page_no:
                next_link = replace_query_param(url, page_param, page_no + 1)
            if page_no > 1:
                prev_link = replace_query_param(url, page_param, page_no - 1)
            return next_link, prev_link
```